# Convergence Radius of complex Function

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Let $f(z) = z^{2} + z +1 $ and $g(z) = \frac{1}{f(z)} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n z^{n}$. Calculate the convergence radius of $g(z)$ and calculate $a_0, a_1, a_2$.

I use taylor expansion to get
\begin{align*}
g(z) = \frac{1}{ z^{2} + z +1} \approx 1 - z + \mathcal{O}(z^{3}) \Rightarrow a_0 = 1, \, a_1 = -1 \,  a_2= 0
\end{align*}
But the full series expansion is (by using Mathematica) something with Chebychev Polynomials. So I'm not sure how to get the convergence radius.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the border of the disc of convergence there has to be a singularity. This means that the radius of divergence is governed by the zeroes of $z^2+z+1$ that is ${-1\pm i\sqrt3 \over 2}$.

As $|{-1\pm i\sqrt3 \over 2}|=1$ you get the convergence radius to be $1$.

Answer (score 2):

Hint. Note that for $|z|<1$,
$$\frac{1}{z^2+z+1}=\frac{1-z}{1-z^3}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{3k}-\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}z^{3k+1}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_nz^n.$$
where $a_n=1$ if $3$ divides $n$, $a_n=-1$ if $3$ divides $n-1$ and $0$ otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

In order to compute $a_0$, $a_1$ and $a_2$, you can do this:$$(a_0+a_1z+a_2z^2+\cdots)(1+z+z^2)=1\iff a_0+(a_0+a_1)z+(a_0+a_1+a_2)z^2+\cdots=1.$$Therefore$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}a_0=1\\a_0+a_1=0\\a_0+a_1+a_2=0\end{array}\right.$$and the solution of this system is $a_0=1$, $a_1=-1$, and $a_2=0$.